# Nice example for a splitting short exact sequence of vector bundles

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles, exact-sequence

I am preparing an introduction to banach manifolds and currently I am working on exact sequences of vector bundles of banach manifolds. Are there any nice examples (i.e. easy to understand for people who do not have any knowledge on this subject yet) for a short exact sequence of vector bundle morphisms which splits?

I have thought one could try to use the fundamental theorem of calculus short exact sequence (cf. [Terry Tao's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/q/363804))
given by

> $0 \to \mathbb{R} \to C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \overset{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}}{\to}C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \to 0.$

However, I am not seeing how $\mathbb{R}$ on the LHS becomes a vector bundle.

Comment: "However, I am not seeing how ℝ on the LHS becomes a vector bundle." You _could_ view ℝ as a 1-dimensional vector bundle over a 0-dimensional space, but I am not sure if that's what you are after...

Comment: @student91 Yes, I guess. I thought of that, too. However, then this sequence is nothing more than a sequence of vector spaces, isn't it? So, that is probably what I will choose for the example. But, maybe there is something that uses nontrivial vector-bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple example is to start with a short exact sequence of finite dimensional vector *spaces*, i.e. a sequence
$$
0\to U\xrightarrow{f}V\xrightarrow{g}W\to 0
$$
where $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective, and $\operatorname{im}(f)=\ker(g)$. Since all such sequences split, the corresponding sequence of trivial vector bundles will split in the corresponding way. For instance, in $\mathsf{Vect}(M)$ we have:
$$
M\times 0\to M\times U\xrightarrow{\operatorname{id_M\times f}}M\times V\xrightarrow{\operatorname{id_M\times g}}M\times W\to M\times 0
$$